# Head First C string.h related questions

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reverse(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *t = s + len - 1;
    while (t >= s)
    {
        printf("%c", *t);
        t = t - 1;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Above is a function that will display a string backward on the screen. But I don't understand the 7th line (char *t = s+ len-1;). Could anybody explain this is spoken English please?

Comment: `char *t = s+ len-1;` points to the last character of the string.

Comment: What is the last index of an array of `len` elements?

Comment: You might also want to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about *pointers* and *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: This doesn't work if `strlen()` return `0`.

Comment: ....or if s is not nul-terminated.... but is not constructive here...

Comment: @Stargateur Of if `s` is not a valid pointer, or points to an unterminated string, or many other possible things.

Comment: But technically, the code is illegal since `t` will be left pointing to 1 `char` before the array passed to it, and the comparison `t >= s` may not work.

Comment: See also [fputc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fputc.html) and [putc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putc.html).

Comment: `char *t = s + len - 1;` is undefined behavior if the input string is empty, and `t = t - 1;` is always undefined behavior when `t` points to the beginning of `s`, since it is UB to even form this address with pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 7):

For starters this function

```
void print_reverse(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *t = s + len - 1;
    while (t >= s)
    {
        printf("%c", *t);
        t = t - 1;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

is wrong and has undefined behavior.:)

There are two problems.

The first one is that the passed string as the argument can have a zero-length. In this case this declaration

```
char *t = s + len - 1;
```

will look like

```
char *t = s - 1;
```

and the pointer `t` can be wrong.

The second problem is that this expression statement

```
t = t - 1;
```

has undefined behavior in case when the pointer `t` is equal to `s`.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 8. ...If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same
>      array object, or one past the last element of the array
>      object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the
>      behavior is undefined**.

A correct function implementation can look the following way

```
void print_reverse( const char *s)
                    ^^^^^
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    const char *t = s + len;
                    ^^^^^^^
    while (t != s)
           ^^^^^^
    {
        printf("%c", *--t);
                     ^^^^
    }
    puts("");
}
```

As for your question then in this declaration

```
char *t = s + len - 1;
```

the pointer `t` is tried to be initialized by the address of the last character of the string before the terminating zero.

Comment: Made my comment under OP, then saw your answer. If this is example code from the book, it does not speak well of "Head First C".

Comment: @DavidBowling I'm unemployed. I do not know such details.:)

Answer (score 2):

Main logic behind this functions is that this code:

```
char *t = s+ len-1;
```

return a pointer to the address of the last char in the char pointer you are passing to the function. The loop prints it by decrementing it:

```
t = t - 1;
```

So in simple words it prints the char pointer from backwards.